# How to draw random numbers from a normal distribution with given mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, normal-distribution

I'm trying to draw random numbers from a normal distribution with given **mean**, **variance**, **skewness** and **kurtosis**.

My first attempt was to use the numpy function random.normal however to this function as far as i understand i can only pass a location (*mean*) and a scale (*std*) parameter.

Second attempt is to draw random numbers from the uniform distribution in the **interval [0,1]** and then pass them through the *scipy.stats.norm* method ppf. I see that **scipy** has the ability to treat skewness and kurtosis, however i cannot see how i can pass skewness and kurtosis values into the function.

If the problem should be solved in an entirely different way please let me know.

Attempt 1:

```
import numpy as np

def draw_normal():
    return np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1) # how to pass skew and kurtosis (excess kurtosis) to the function
```

Attempt 2

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm


def draw_uniform():
    return np.random.uniform(0,1)

def draw_normal_alt():
    return norm.ppf(draw_uniform(),loc=0, scale=1) #how to pass skew and kurtosis (excess kurtosis) to func
```

Comment: *The* normal distribution has fixed skewness (`0`) and kurtosis (`3`, if I remember correctly).  I don't see that it makes sense to input arguments for those measures to the routines.

Comment: Once you have set the mean and variance of the normal distribution, the distribution is completely determined--there are no more parameters that can be changed.  Also, the skewness and the excess kurtosis of the normal distribution are both 0, so it doesn't make sense to try to set them to anything else.

Comment: According to [this page on kurtosis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KurtosisExcess.html) and [this page for skewness](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Skewness.html) those have fixed values for the uniform distribution. So you do **not** want a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is not a normal distribution anymore. You should look into other kinds of distributions. 
Note that there are many distributions with the same mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis.

For a python function that generates what you want, see [this](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.distributions.extras.pdf_mvsk.html#statsmodels.sandbox.distributions.extras.pdf_mvsk).